# How to apply CHMOD command to any file with a specific name recursively in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface

I need to know how to apply a CHMOD command to only files that have a specific name recursively?

```
chmod 755 -R filename
```

Something like above but it should apply to any `filename` that exists in any sub folders.

Comment: do you want to apply this to a filename or a file type ie .html, .php etc

Comment: Just a file with the name `filename`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will find all files named filename, recursively from the current directory, and pass them to `chmod`.

```
find -name filename | xargs chmod 755
```

See the manpages for `find` and `xargs` for more advanced options. In particular, look at the `-print0` flag and corresponding `-0` to `xargs` if you get errors about files with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a exec parameter in find that will do the same:

```
find . -name filename -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: The trade off here is execution efficiency.  Xargs will only call chmod approximately the minimum number of times necessary for the number of files, the exec option to find will call it once for each file found.

Comment: However, if your version of `find` supports it, you can use a `+` instead of the `\;` to get `xargs`-like functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the best of both worlds if you use the `+` operator to find to make it run `chmod` on many files at once.

```
find . -name filename -exec chmod 755 '{}' +
```

You should always put a `'` around your `{}`, otherwise a filename with a space in it could mess things up. In this case it's not a problem, but I have a habit of doing it.